# Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'CartItem'

Tags: angular, typescript, undefined, variable-assignment

*I get the error 'Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'CartItem' during running my program, I could not resolve the error :(.*

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CartItem } from '../common/cart-item';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class CartService {
  cartItems: CartItem[] = [];

  totalPrice: Subject<number> = new Subject<number>();
  totalQuantity: Subject<number> = new Subject<number>();

  constructor() {}

  addToCart(theCartItem: CartItem) {
    // check if we already have the item in our cart
    let alreadyExistsInCart: boolean = false;
    let existingCartItem: CartItem = undefined; // ERROR HERE
  }
}
```

Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'CartItem' I'm getting an errorhow do I resolve this error

Comment: SUGGESTION: Consider using your CartService `constructor ()` to initialize member variables cartItems, totalPrice and totalQuantity.  Also consider explicitly specifying access (e.g. `private`)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: _thank you for your interest **let existingCartItem: CartItem = undefined;** Replace **let existingCartItem: CartItem | undefined;** problem solved when I typed_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is just the error

```
let existingCartItem: CartItem | undefined;
```

that will initialize `existingCartItem` to `undefined`.

Comment: Hi Ahmet - I edited your code to focus on the question you were asking.  I know you were thinking that the definition of `CartItem` might be involved in the error, but that is not so.  Any class is an object type, and an object type never includes `undefined`.  (Unless the compiler options `strict` and `strictNullChecks` are both false - but that is not common practice).  It should never be wrong to ask a question about what you don't understand.  If this answer was helpful, you may upvote or even select it as the correct answer and you will get some points for that.